# Why is my code not waiting to output in this asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

So here is my code:
What should happen is that my code should wait 3 seconds before returning the promise resolve('hello bruh'). Then it should output it. But for some reason I always get this weird problem where straight up returning from an async function doesn't work with await, but return new Promise ( (resolve , reject) => { // do stuff} ) will.

Instead my output in the console is :

```
basic2()  
async-js-learning.js:157 here undefined 
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}[[Prototype]]:
Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled" 
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

I don't really get why my promise is undefined when I used await. I'm a beginner in JS so any help
would be appreciated. thx.

```
async function basic1() {
   setTimeout(()=>'hello bruh' , 3000);
}

async function basic2() {
  let data = await basic1();
  console.log('here' ,data);
}
```

Comment: there's nothing to await coming from `basic1` ... where's the promise? (async/await works with promises, not just anything that may be asynchronous in nature) - one of the biggest issues with async/await is that it isn't obvious, unless you read the documentation, what you can await and what you can't - so, it comes down to understanding the code you write by reading documentation

Comment: Your `basic1()` function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions return promises, but since you're not returning anything from the function it makes the `async` part meaningless.

So, `basic1` doesn't need to be async. But you can return a promise from it and `await` for it in `basic2`.

```js
function basic1() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(()=> res('hello bruh') , 3000);
  });
}

async function basic2() {
  let data = await basic1();
  console.log('here' ,data);
}

basic2();
```

Comment: Oh ok. I was under the impression that returning something inside an async function is the same thing as returning a resolved promise with the specified data. Is that not the case?

Comment: @WaadlingPenguin your function does not return anything. Returning a value from a `setTimeout()` callback does nothing.